# Remove empty nested lists - Python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists, python-3.5

I'm reading in a .csv file to a list and it appends an empty lists, I'm using the code below to do this.

```
with open('Scores.csv', 'r') as scores:
    reader = csv.reader(scores)
    tscores = [[str(e) for e in r] for r in reader]
```

It creates a list of nested lists correctly but appends an empty list after every row read in like so:

```
[[score1, name1], [], [score2, name2], []]
```

I believe it's reading `\n` as an empty string which is why I'm getting that, so I tried to remove empty lists using:

```
tscores = [tscores.remove(x) for x in tscores if x]
```

which does delete empty nested lists, but it sets all other nested lists that contained data to `None` i.e. `[None, None]`. I modified to:

```
tscores = [tscores.remove(x) for x in tscores if []]
```

which wipes out all nested lists completely.

How can I read the file with the same output (a list of nested lists) without appending empty lists or how can I remove all empty lists after being read in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to do is

```
tscores = [x for x in tscores if x != []]
```

which make a list of only the none empty lists in tscores

Answer (score 1):

Alternative to [user2990008's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33468632/15055), you can not create the empty lists in the first place:

```
tscores = [[str(e) for e in r] for r in reader if len(r) > 0]
```

Comment: This seems like a good answer too and probably the most appropriate. EDIT: This definitely works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness: In such cases I think that list comprehensions are not the most simple solution. Here functional programming would make sense, imho.

To "automatically" iterate over a list and filter specific elements, you could use the built-in function [filter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
In [89]: a = [ [1, 2], [], [3, 4], [], [5, 6], [], [], [9, 5, 2, 5]]

In [91]: filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, a)
Out[91]: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [9, 5, 2, 5]]
```

Every element `x` of the list `a` is passed to the `lambda` function and the returned list only contains an element of `a` if and only if the condition `len(x) > 0` is met. Therefore a list without the nested empty lists is returned.

Comment: Hmm... `filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, a)` is worse in every way than `[x for x in a if len(x) > 0]` - slower and less idiomatic for the same effect.

Comment: In Python it should be slower because of the function calls are inefficient, yes - generally it depends on the implementation. However, for filtering-purposes I (personally) like this nevertheless because it is more intuitive. This scenario is like one of the most default cases for `filter()`. Admittedly this is an opinion-based decision and just my thoughts..

Comment: Yeah, what I tend to do is if the function already exists/is defined elsewhere, I use `filter`/`map` (e.g. `map(str.strip, strs)` instead of `[x.strip() for x in strs]`, `filter(is_gormed, maybe_gorms)` instead of `[x for x in maybe_gorms if is_gormed(x)]`), but if I need an expression then I use list comprehensions. People may disagree even with these uses of map/filter - the list comprehensions really are easier on the eyes (maybe subjective) and are used more often

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm understanding your question correctly, but you can remove the empty entries from a list of lists (or a list of tuples or a list of other sequences) using something like this:

```
#/bin/python
# ...
with open('Scores.csv', 'r') as scores:
    reader = csv.reader(scores)
    tscores = [[str(e) for e in r] for r in reader if len(r)]
```

... remember that your list comprehension can handle optional conditional clauses for filtering.  This will only work if you can ensure that every element of the list that you're traversing support the *len()* function (of course you can ensure this by using a more complex condition such as: *hasattr(r, '**len**') and len(r)*

Note: this only tests one level of depth ... it is *not* recursive.

Answer (score 0):

```
tscores = [x for x in tscores if x]
```

If the list is empty the conditional will return false, and therefore will not be included in `tscores`.